# Ruby: Get value if true or

Tags: ruby

I can use a ternary operator like this:

```
a.empty? ? a : b
```

If `a` is just a short variable, this works. If I don't want to use a variable but, for example, I'm within a complex chain of array functions where i have no temp variables, how to  this without having to repeat the chain? This seems to me to only work with nil values where I can use  `or`

```
a.filter { bla bla bla }.map { bla bla bla }.reduce { bla bla } || b
```

But for any other kind of check how to do this?

```
a.filter { bla bla bla }.map { bla bla bla }.reduce { bla bla }.empty? ? a.filter { bla bla bla }.map { bla bla bla }.reduce { bla bla } : b
```

Comment: One question with the first line. if a is `empty` why would you want to have that execute again? Am I wrong in thinking: "if filter-> map -> reduce gives you an empty result, you want to run it again, why?"

Comment: Somehow using temp variables is not an option?

Comment: I'd just check for empty? after filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been asked repeatedly:

```
a
.filter{bla bla bla}
.map{bla bla bla}
.reduce{bla bla}
.tap{|a| break a.empty? ? a : b}
```

or, alternatively (which is not recommended):

```
a
.filter{bla bla bla}
.map{bla bla bla}
.reduce{bla bla}
.instance_eval{empty? ? self : b}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the value from the first part to a variable, then use it in the second part:

```
(temp = a.filter { bla bla bla }.map { bla bla bla }.reduce { bla bla }).empty? ? b : temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Use (or copy) [`presence`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) that `active_support` defines exactly for this:

```
a.filter{ bla bla bla }
 .map { bla bla bla }
 .reduce{ bla bla }
 .presence || b
```